# Арифметические операции в Срезах и Pep8

Tags: python, pep8

Как правильно писать срезы с арифметическими операциями?

arr[i-1::-1]

Или

arr[i - 1 :: -1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что говорит [pep8checker](http://pep8online.com).
Так можно:

```
arr[i-1::-1]
arr[i - 1:: -1]
arr[i - 1::-1]
```

Как не нужно:

```
arr[i-1 ::-1] # whitespace before ':'
```

Comment: А между тем PEP8 второй случай запрещает. В срезах двоеточия должны выделяться одинаковым количеством пробелов с обеих сторон, кроме случая, когда параметр среза пропущен. в этом случае пробел можно опускать. Т.е. по PEP8 второй случай должен выглядеть так: `arr[i - 1 :: -1]`